# SQL Server Change Tracking between two Express servers?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication

Can I replicate my data (sql server 2008 express) using SQL Server Change Tracking to a read-only server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own one-way synchronization with SQL Server Change Tracking using SQL Server 2008 Express. You can find the information you should need here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462.aspx, and see that it is supported in Express here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx (under replication).